# Align checkbox inside a card

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using [materializecss](https://materializecss.com), and i'm trying to align a checkbox into a card:

```
<div id="email-list" class="col s10 m8 l8 card-panel z-depth-1">
   <ul class="collection">
      <li class="collection-item avatar email-unread">
         <input type="checkbox" />
         <div class="mail-card-el">
            <span class="circle red lighten-1">A</span>
            <span class="email-title">Test card</span>
            <p class="truncate grey-text ultra-small">Summer sale is now going on.</p>
            <a href="#!" class="secondary-content email-time">
            <span class="blue-text ultra-small">12:10 am</span>
            </a>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The problem, I think,  is that the element "circle" is doing something that affects the checkbox, causing to don't show

```
#email-list .collection .collection-item.avatar .circle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

I was trying to "play" with the positions of the elements and i got nothing, what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qJWEyE)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see it, it's nothing wrong with your CSS.
However, the `materialize.min.css` sets the opacity to 0.

This is, because Materialize uses custom checkboxes (like bootstrap) and you can't just put a default HTML-Checkbox in your Code.

First of all you should import the [JS-Files](https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html).

Now, instead of just typing: `<input type="checkbox" />`, you need to wrap your checkbox in `<label>`-Tags. After your checkbox follows a `<span>`-Tag.

Replace your checkbox with:

```
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" />
   <span><!--Text inside here is optional--></span>
</label>
```

and implement the JS-File.
Here is a working code example:

```css
#email-list .collection .collection-item.avatar {
  height: auto;
  padding-left: 72px;
  position: relative;
}

#email-list .collection .collection-item.avatar .secondary-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}

#email-list .collection .collection-item.avatar .secondary-content.email-time {
  right: 8px;
}

#email-list .collection .collection-item.avatar .icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  top: 20px;
}

#email-list .collection .collection-item.avatar .circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 10px;
}

#email-list .collection .collection-item.avatar img.circle {
  padding: 0;
}

#email-list .collection .collection-item:hover {
  background: #e1f5fe;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#email-list .collection .collection-item.selected {
  background: #e1f5fe;
  border-left: 4px solid #29b6f6;
}

#email-list .attach-file {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  color: #bdbdbd;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="email-list" class="col s10 m8 l8 card-panel z-depth-1">
  <ul class="collection">
    <li class="collection-item avatar email-unread">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span></span>
      </label>
      <div class="mail-card-el">
        <span class="circle red lighten-1">A</span>
        <span class="email-title">Test card</span>
        <p class="truncate grey-text ultra-small">Summer sale is now going on.</p>
        <a href="#!" class="secondary-content email-time">
          <span class="blue-text ultra-small">12:10 am</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

A guide and documentation can be found on their [website](https://materializecss.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with materialize, but their css has this:

```
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked), [type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none
}
```

In order to adjust and see the check box you'd need to change the opacity and left and right positions.  Something like:

```
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked), [type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
}
```

You can adjust top and left so the check box aligns where you want it.  I'd also suggest adding a class to the checkbox and use your new class selector to update the style, instead of overwriting the materialize file.

something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="my-checkbox" />

.my-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I went to [the Materialize documentation](https://materializecss.com/checkboxes.html) and found it fairly unhelpful. The stuff they are saying about the label and applying the `for="inputID"` stuff was irrelevant. I got it to work by adding a `span` after the checkbox:

 `<input type="checkbox" /><span>Checkbox Label</span>`

Forked pen:
https://codepen.io/vipatron/pen/EdYjYx

Update: Okay, after I went back to it, I realize that the behavior that Materialize promises "on click" of the checkbox DOES require the `<label>` tag to wrap the `<input>`. (An example is in the codepen). I still don't know too much about what behavior the for/id is supposed to supply, but I do know it's good practice for semantic HTML.